# Is there a way to auto-width or auto-height a control in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, autosize

I have a FlowLayoutPanel with some buttons inside. I want the FlowLayoutPanel width to be the same as the biggest button, but the height to be fixed. How can I accomplish that? I have googled it but all I found was about WPF.

Comment: The title of question is too general. You can use different solutions for different controls. As a general rule for controls which have built-in `AutoSize` support, if you set `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` of the control, the value is usually respected by auto-size routines. 

For example for `FlowLayoutPanel`, you can achieve desired layout by setting minimum height and maximum height and height of `FlowLayoutPanel` to the same fixed value and set its `AutoSize` to true. Also you need to set `FlowDirection` to `TopDown` and `WrapContents` to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply LINQ through the controls and find the maximum width of your buttons:

```
int maxWidth = flp.Controls.OfType<Button>().Max(x => x.Width) + 
              (flp.Margin.Left + flp.Margin.Right);
flp.ClientSize = new Size(maxWidth, flp.ClientSize.Height);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this by setting the anchors on your controls accordingly.

Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx)
and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms171633(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Could you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/) I think this article describes it quite good. The idea is that you can set fixed positions for certain edges of your controls (top, down, left, right). With this you can achieve a nice scaling on your winForms. So if you set up your Form the way you want it and then set the anchors, it should look good even i a user resizes your form.

Comment: I cannot mark it as answered when the answer is a link... It's a law of StackOverflow I think...

Comment: @MichaelHaddad That's if it's *just* a link. This answer has more.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance - Well... It is marked as answered for several years now :)